# Simple way of changing the font of a dynamically created ToolTip in C# windows forms?

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

Anyone have any idea on how to change the font of a dynamically created `ToolTip`? What I usually do in `Label` is

```
string arialUnicodeFontFace = "Arial Unicode MS";
            Font unicodeFont = new Font(arialUnicodeFontFace, 8);
            if (unicodeFont.Name != arialUnicodeFontFace)
                unicodeFont = new Font("NSimSun", 8);

Label lbl = new Label();
lbl.Font = unicodeFont;
    for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++)
            {
TextBox txt = new TextBox();
                txt.Name = dt.Rows[x]["field_name"].ToString();
                txt.Width = 200;
                txt.Height = 10;
                ToolTip tooltip = new ToolTip();
foreach (DataRow row in dtchnge.Rows)
            {


                if (dt.Rows[x]["definition"].ToString() == row["term"].ToString())
                {
                    tooltip.SetToolTip(txt, row["language_based_term"].ToString());
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why are you not using an actual tool-tip?

Comment: @YoryeNathan, because my tooltip caption is based from db. and the number of tool tip is also based on db

Comment: You can still do it within the code... `new ToolTip()` is just as good as creating one at design time.

Comment: I updated how i generate the tooltip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic `ToolTip` is drawn by the Operating System, if you want to Customize it you will need to set the [OwnerDraw property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.ownerdraw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to true and handle the Custom Fonts in the [Draw Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.draw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) like the MSDN example shows.

From first Link:

> Usually, a ToolTip is drawn by the operating system, but to customize
>   the appearance of the ToolTip you can set the OwnerDraw property to
>   true and handle the Draw event.
>
> The IsBalloon property takes precedence over the OwnerDraw property.
>   If both are set to true, the ToolTip will be displayed using a balloon
>   window rather than an owner drawn window.